# Initial app load tab bar tint blinking

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard, tint

When iOS application starts then all tab bar icons have default tint (light blue). I setup my own custom tint color in `viewDidLoad`. But it applies with delay and I see transition between default tint color and my custom tint color. How can I apply my custom tint color to tab bar before interface will appear and eliminate color blinking?

Comment: Try this in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Set the tint here after the view has been loaded completely
    }
```

Comment: Has same blink effect. I see default tint and then it changes to my color.

Answer (score 0):

So this is because the default is set when the application finishes launching, and then is changed when your view controller is initialized. To do this, you want to change the tab bar tint globally.

Do this in your `AppDelegate.m` file in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method.

Use `[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:(UIColor *)];` to set the tint of your tab bar across the entire application, where `(UIColor *)` is of course replaced by the color you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried with no success. Of course translated in swift as `UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = ...`. It has same effect as described in question. First of all I see default blue tint but then (in a 1 second) it changes to my custom color.